# How to get a string from Observable in an observables chain?

Tags: rxjs, ngrx-effects

I have ngrx Effect which deals with a login action. The last `switchMap` returns a token string which is supposed to be passed to the next observable. When I launch the app, the last `switchMap` indeed returns a token string, but the next `mergeMap` operator received only the first character of the token string.

How to pass the full string into the mergeMap operator? Maybe I should use some other operator to achieve this, but which one then?

```
@Effect()
  authLogin = this.actions$.ofType(AuthActions.TRY_LOGIN)
    .map((action: AuthActions.TryLogin) => {
      return action.payload;
    })
    .switchMap((authData: { username: string, password: string }) => {
      return this.http.post(this.apiName + 'auth/login', authData);
    })
    .switchMap((respons: any) => {
      return respons;
    })
    .mergeMap((token: string) => {    
      return [
        {
          type: AuthActions.LOGIN
        },
        {
          type: AuthActions.SET_TOKEN,
          payload: token
        }
      ];
    })
    .take(1)
    .do(() => {
      this.router.navigate(['profile']).catch(err => console.warn(err));
    })
    .catch(err => {
      throw 'ERROR IN TRY SIGN IN EFFECT. DETAILS: ' + err;
    });
```

Comment: If you are returning a string, use `map` instead of `switchMap`. The latter expects an `ObservableInput` to be returned. That's why it flattens the string's character into the stream.

Comment: What's this supposed to do anyway `.switchMap((respons: any) => { respons; })`?

Comment: And you should move the error handling, etc to inside the first `switchMap`. If your effect sees an error it will complete and will cease handling actions.

Comment: Um.. I think it's redundant. Thanks for pointing out.